# Formatting json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and I need to change the format of json that I am taking in.
I have json in this format

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00",
    "end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00",
    "users":[{"id":2,"firstName":"John"}]
}
```

I need the json to be like this

```
{
    "start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00",
    "end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00",
    "text": "John"
}
```

Where the users first name is set to text. Im not very familiar with javascript so i dont know how to iterate through this json and reformat it?

EDITED: I am fetching the json from a file 
This is my code

```
let ob1 = fetch('db.json')
        let mapped = {
            "start": ob1.start,
            "end": ob1.end,
            "text": ob1.usersShifts.map(curElem => {return curElem.firstName}) + ""
        }
        console.log(mapped)
```

My issue now that start end and text are all undefined

Comment: Can you provide a small [mcve] to be sure of what you have here ? Is this already an object or just a JSON in plain text ?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: The "users" property is an Array and as such may have multiple user objects each with their own "firstName". How do you decide which to put into "text"?

Comment: Share some code or look this link. If you want to extract the json and creating new json.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: I am fetching the json like this
````
var json = fetch('db.json')
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just to map it to another element and

for `users` i assume it's array so

```
ob1.users.map(curElem => {return curElem.firstName}) + ""
```

you will need `+ ""` to convert the array to String if more than 1

```js
    let ob1 = {
        "id": "3",
        "start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00",
        "end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00",
        "users":[{"id":2,"firstName":"John"}]
    }

  let mapped = {
  "start": ob1.start,
  "end": ob1.end,
  "text": ob1.users.map(curElem => {return curElem.firstName}) + ""
  }
console.log(mapped)
 
 // here if you have multiple users and you want the result based on the users 
let result = []
ob1.users.forEach(currUser => {
  result.push( {
     "start": ob1.start,
     "end": ob1.end,
     "text": currUser.firstName
     })
   })

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```js
const oldData =     {
        "id": "3",
        "start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00",
        "end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00",
        "users":[{"id":2,"firstName":"John"}]
    }

const newData = {
    start: oldData.start, 
    end: oldData.end, 
    text: oldData.users[0].firstName
  }

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This works when i am inputing the json myself but I am fetching the json from a file using the fetch command

Answer (score 1):

Check this out,

```html
<script>

function format(){

var oldData = {
        "id": "3",
        "start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00",
        "end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00",
        "users":[{"id":2,"firstName":"John"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Peter"}]
    }
    
var newData = [];

var i = oldData.users.length;
var k = 0;

while(k < i){

var temp_array = {
  "start":oldData.start,
  "end":oldData.end,
  "text":oldData.users[k]["firstName"]
}

newData.push(temp_array);

k++;
}

console.log(newData);


}

format();
</script>
```

Comment: how do i define the length?

Comment: Which length you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you will only ever have one user in the list of users as it will select the first user...

```js
let json_data = [
    {
        "id": "3",
        "start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00",
        "end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00",
        "users":[{"id":2,"firstName":"John"}]
    },
];

let output = [];
json_data.forEach(function(item) {
    output.push({"start": item.start, "end": item.end, "text": item.users[0].firstName});
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the input data is a JSON string.

You need to parse the JSON string to a javascript object, then modify it and parse it back to a JSON string:

```js
var json = '{"id": "3","start": "2019-04-15T09:00:00","end": "2019-04-15T11:00:00","users":[{"id":2,"firstName":"John"}]}';

var inputData = JSON.parse(json);

var outputData = {
  start: inputData.start, 
  end: inputData.end, 
  text: inputData.users[0].firstName
};

var output = JSON.stringify(outputData);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: the inputData.users[0].firstName isnt working, the error states 'cant read property 0 of undefined. It might be due to the fact that i have a few users

Comment: This happens when "users" is null or undefined. You need to describe what the "users" property exactly contains and what you want to display in the "text" property.